# what is the postgresql query to find the timestamp without time zone

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
select now();
               now
----------------------------------
 2019-06-01 16:10:19.893354+05:30
```

I want only date and time without timezone.What is the query to get today's date and time.eg: 2019-06-01 16:10:19

Comment: TBH: this is most likely **not** what you want. Stripping off time zone may lead to some very weird and unpredictable behaviour. At least do cast to a fixed time zone first, e.g. `select now() at time zone 'UTC';`. More importantly: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

You can cast the value:

```
select CAST(now() as timestamp without time zone)
```

If you don't want the milliseconds, you can use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(CAST(now() as timestamp without time zone), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: select now() at time zone 'UTC';
          timezone
----------------------------
 2019-06-01 10:53:09.523928

Comment: I want ouput as: 2019-06-01 10:53:09

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to timestamp in this way of current time :

```
select now()::timestamp() without time zone
```

And you can use timestamp(0) if you do now want miliseconds. The number in timestamp('number') is miliseconds after dot of seconds

You need that query :

```
select now()::timestamp(0) without time zone
```

Comment: select now()::timestamp without time zone;
            now
----------------------------
 2019-06-01 16:24:46.294927

Comment: I want o/p as 2019-06-01 16:24:46

Comment: It is the easiset and elegant way of what you needed @rekha